# jQuery datepicker fire alert if is tomorrow

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

I would like an alert to fire if the date selected is tomorrow. This is what I have:

```
$('#dateInput').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        if (Date.parse(today)+1 == Date.parse(selectedDate)) {
            alert('tomorrow!');
        }
    }
});
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Do you want to fire alert at just tomorrow or all month days same as tomorrow ?

Answer (score 1):

This will be fired on just tomorrow, not all month same day of tomorrow:

```
$('#dateInput').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date_now = new Date();
        var date_today = date_now.getDate();
        var date_thismonth = date_now.getMonth();
        var date_thisyear = date_now.getFullYear();
        if (date_thisyear == inst.selectedYear && 
            date_thismonth == inst.selectedMonth && 
            (date_today+1) == inst.selectedDay){
            alert('tomorrow!');
        }
    }
});?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ue9Lh/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dateInput').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       var todayDate = new Date();
       var tomorrowDate = new Date(todayDate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).setHours(0,0,0,0);
       var inputDate = new Date(dateText);
       if (tomorrowDate - inputDate == 0) {
        alert('tomorrow!');
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dateInput').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var tomorrow = new Date();
        tomorrow.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate()+1);
        if (tomorrow.getTime() == Date.parse(dateText)) {
            alert('tomorrow!');
        }
   }
});
```